# In JPA can I access the field created by the @OrderColumn into the collected entity?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

My sample code:

```
 public class A {

  @OneToMany
  @OrderColumn(name = "ORDER")
  private List<B> bList;
  ...
 }

 public class B {

  @Column(name = "ORDER")
  private Integer order; // I need this field because I want 
                         // to use the ordering field in my query.
  ...
 }
```

With this code EclipseLink try to create the "ORDER" column 2 times throwing an exception and don't create the B table.

Thanks.

Comment: why not define *how* you want to use the ordering in a query

Comment: Simply like this: SELECT b FROM B b WHERE ... ORDER BY order

Comment: So do as James said ... use "ORDER BY INDEX(list)"

Comment: I tried but don't work with EclipseLink

Answer (score 2):

Please log a bug for this issue on EclipseLink.

You should not need the column just for querying, you can use the JPQL INDEX(bList) to query the order column.

In EclipseLink you can also use a DescriptorCustomizer to define a QueryKey for any column to allow querying on it.

Comment: ok but is not possible to use it in the "order by" query section

Answer (score 1):

Use @OrderBy instead of @OrderColumn. Look at reference 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html

Comment: Why would he do that if he wanted an indexed list, rather than an ordered list? They are different concepts, with one preserving the order the elements were added to the list, and the other imposing some query-based order on them